# Showing that the sequence of functions defined by $f_n(x):=\frac{n^2x+n}{n^2+n+1}$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and $n \in \Bbb N$ is converges to $g(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $(f_n):\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a sequence of functions defined by $f_n(x):=\frac{n^2x+n}{n^2+n+1}$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and $n \in \Bbb N$. Let $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function defined by $g(x):=x$. Prove that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $g$ on $\Bbb R$.

How to prove it by the $\varepsilon-x$ definition, that is, the definition of converges pointwise?
Should I start the proof by divide into some cases, like for $x=0,x=1,x \in (0,1)$, etc?

**Edit:**
Firstly, I compute $|f_n(x)-x|$ as follow:
\begin{equation*}
\left|\frac{n^2x+n}{n^2+n+1} - x\right| = \left|\frac{n-nx-x}{n^2+n+1}\right|.
\end{equation*}

Any idea? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Start by computing $|f_n(x)-x|$.

Comment: @copper.hat Done. What's next???

Comment: Divide above and below by $n^2$.

Comment: Write out what copper.hat suggested, finding a common denominator. Then factor out $n^2$ from top and bottom.

Comment: OK done. And what's next? How to start the epsilon proof?

Comment: Could you give me your opinion about my post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379589/showing-that-the-given-sequence-of-functions-converges-to-a-given-function-on-th ?

Comment: Simplify your life by noting that $|{ \text{stuff} \over 1+\text{other stuff}}| \le | \text {stuff}|$ since the other stuff is non negative.

Comment: Remember that $x$ is unknown but fixed, and the parameters you choose will depend on $x$ (or $|x|$, or similar).

Comment: $|\frac{x+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}} - x| \le |x+\frac{1}{n}|$. Like this?

Comment: @krewlpt You must have made a mistake somewhere, because you are missing a few terms. Divide above and below by $n^2$ in the formula in your edit.

Comment: See Clement's answer below.

Comment: @copper.hat OK Sir. Thanks. What about my other post above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite:
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{n^2x + n}{n^2 + n + 1} = \frac{x + \frac{1}{n}}{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}}
$$
So it's clear (at least intuitively) that if $n \to \infty$ then $f_n(x) \to x$. To do this rigorously, we have:
$$
|f_n(x) - x| = \left|\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}x + \frac{1}{n}\right)}{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}}\right| \leq \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)|x| + \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{2}{n}|x| + \frac{1}{n}
$$
So for any $\epsilon > 0$ let $n$ be large enough so that $\frac{1}{n} < \min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{4|x|},\frac{1}{n} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}$. If $x = 0$, then $|f_n(0) - 0| \leq \frac{1}{n}$, so simply let $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Sorry, I think you have a typo. Does the second equality means $\left|\frac{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{x}{n^2} - \frac{x}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}}  \right|$ ?

Comment: How to choose $n$? Like this: Choose $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n = \max\{\frac{\varepsilon |x|}{4}, \frac{\varepsilon}{2}  \}$ ?

Comment: No, I used triangle inequality there. And choose any $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \max\left\{\frac{\epsilon|x|}{4},\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}$.

Comment: Why not choosing $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \max\{\frac{\varepsilon}{4|x|}, \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}$ sir ?

Comment: Sorry yes, it should be $\frac{\epsilon}{4|x|}$. Also, it should be $\frac{1}{n} < \min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{4|x|},\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}$, not $\max$.

Comment: OK. But, how if $x=0$ ? The numerator would be equal to $0$.

Comment: Then $|f_n(0) - 0| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ already, so simply let $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Aaah I see. So basically, the above proof is refer to the case when $x \ne 0$, right? And for the case $x=0$, we could just using the Archimedean Principle, right?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot, Sir.